# How to read register values at specific instructions in C++ like Cheat Engine does?

Tags: c++, assembly, cpu-registers, cheat-engine

The example of what I mean:

Here I move rcx register value into a _Player symbol.
rcx is the address of Player Object.

The address of instructions is for e.g. module.dll+FFFF.

I want to move register value into variable in my external C++ application.

```
alloc(code, $1000, module.dll+FFFF)

code:
  push rbx
  sub rsp,40
  mov [_Player], rcx
  jmp return
```

How can I do something similar in C++ if it is possible?

Also if you need more precise information about what I want. Please inform me.

Edit:

The Offsets for Object are always dynamic, they change.
But the instructions remain static. In this case, pointer scanning is not possible, because I would need to manually respecify the offsets after each game that point to the player object.

Comment: Why not just use [inline assembly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm)?

Comment: @txtechhelp I do not think that's the way to do it. It is just simply for function calls that are related to my own program, but not the external one.

If I'm wrong here, then how do I do it. I'm a beginner at the assembly thing.

Comment: You'll need assembly to mess with the `rcx` register, but essentially you're going to have to look into _reverse engineering DLL's_ and _dependency injection_ to get what you want. Depending on the game, it might have anti-cheat measures and make your task a little more difficult. There's a lot that goes into reverse engineering and dll exploits, and I don't think you'll be able to get a solid answer without a little more research on your part into reverse engineering (that's not a dig, but answering the question would require pages of explanation and be out of the scope of SO).

Comment: You could also try the [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/). At least to help you get started down that path or point you in the direction you might need.

Comment: *I want to move register value into variable in my external C++ application.* - When?  Do you want to have your program attach to the other process like a debugger, and set a breakpoint so you know every time this code runs?  Or do you want to inject a modified version of this block of code that includes a store to some static address?  Or inject code that makes a system call to write memory in your C++ application (the address of a `volatile uint64_t` perhaps) every time this code runs?

Comment: @PeterCordes I want always, while the instruction is being executed. So something similar to a debugger might be a way to go since all I need is to get the value, that the register stores

Comment: Ok then you probably want to set a breakpoint in the remote process, exactly like a debugger would.  The other option would be to hook that code with some kind of logging code that adds a value (and maybe timestamp) to a buffer every time that code runs.

Comment: @PeterCordes ok, I will look into this and it might solve my problem.